# Trouble understanding this particular Array reduce method

Tags: javascript, reduce

I need a detailed explanation of the Array reduce method I used on an array of objects. The Array reduce method converts the given array into an array of objects based on the matchday value. So it filters the array and stores the objects with the same matchday value in a nested array of objects. I know what the reducer does in general only in this case I'm missing something. Can someone explain this to me? Any help would be appreciated.

```
const data = [
{ id: 301998, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T16:45:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 1 },
{ id: 301999, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T18:00:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 1 },
{ id: 302000, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T19:00:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 1 },


{ id: 302006, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-18T18:00:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 2 },
{ id: 302007, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-19T14:30:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 2 },
{ id: 302008, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-19T16:45:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 2 }
]

let res = Object.values(
data.reduce((acc, m) => {

    acc[ m.matchday ] = acc[ m.matchday ] || [];
    acc[ m.matchday ].push(m);

    return acc;
   }, {})
);
console.log(res) // =>  [ [{…}, {…}, {…}], [{…}, {…}, {…}] ]
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Comment: Please don't send any links, I know how to google, thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry! I have posted an explaination for the same below as an answer. Could you please check ? If you find it helpful, make sure you upvote! thanks

Comment: So you know what reducer does, you probably know what Object.values does, namely that instead of having an object with matchdays as keys (1,2...) you have an array of the values, you described what the code does "So it filters the array and stores the objects with the same matchday value in a nested array of objects.". What is it exactly that you want to know? What part of the code?

Comment: It's basically a groupBy (see an example here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) but without the keys.

Comment: @jperl, what happens on the first iteration? acc is an empty object and the acc[ m.matchday ] is therefore undefined ? so the first loop leaves an empty array, and  the first object  m  is pushed into the empty array. So at that moment we have an object with an array with an object? like so { [ {...} ] }. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that line says if it's not initialized, then initialize it. You would have an error otherwise at the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Object.values**

The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop. (The only difference is that a for...in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.)

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
// expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

**Reduce function**

The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

The reducer function takes four arguments:

The reducer function takes four arguments:

1. Accumulator
2. Current Value
3. Current Index
4. Source Array

In your question,

`data` array is reduced to object of following structure -

```
obj = {
      1: [{ id: 301998, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T16:45:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 1 }, ...],
      2: [{ id: 23412, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T16:45:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 2 }, ...]
}
```

Now, Object.values on above object just returns back array of the above object's (obj) values.

> The returned array would be of length = 'no of unique match days present in data array'

Output -

```
[
   [{ id: 301998, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T16:45:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 1 }, ...],
   [{ id: 23412, season: 2020-2021, utcDate: "2020-09-12T16:45:00Z", status: "FINISHED", matchday: 2 }, ...]
]
```